# Mass and the creation of spatial volume

Tags: general-relativity, mass, curvature

The following question is based on [*"Mass and the creation of spatial volume"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2705) by C.J. Herzenberg:

Let us take Schwarzschild metric in the form

$$
ds^2=\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1} dr^2+r^2(d \theta^2+\sin^2 \theta d \phi^2)-\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right) dt^2
$$
Volume element for the  3d Euclidean space is
$$
dV_0 = dr (r d\theta) (r \sin \theta) d \phi = 4 \pi r^2 dr
$$
For Schwarzschild (assuming $r\gt r_s$)
$$
dV_m = 4 \pi r^2 \left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1/2} dr
$$
This can be integrated exactly, but for  the sake of simplicity let us use an approximation for  $r\gg r_s$
$$
dV_m =4 \pi r^2 \left(1+ \frac{r_s}{2 r}+ \dots\right)dr
$$
Now for the "excess volume" due to the curvature 
$$
d(V_0 - V_m) = 2 \pi r r_s dr 
$$
Excess volume enclosed in the sphere of radius $r$ is thus $\pi r_s r^2$. (This is approximation for $r\gg r_s)$, but exact integration leads to the same leading order result).

So far this was math. **Now my question is: Can this be physically interpreted that each mass particle contributes to the volume of the universe?**

For example, Herzenberg claims that for
the case of a star of solar mass (about $2 \times 10^{30}$ kg) the volume created would correspond
to an excess mass-created volume of about $1.6 \times 10^{56}$ cubic meters (corresponding
approximately to the volume of a region of space roughly 500 light years on a side).

Hypotetically also: in an infinite universe, each grain of sand would have infinite contribution in terms of the "excess volume".

Comment: The notion of a spatial volume you introduce here is non-unique. Try to repeat your calculations in some of the other coordinates in Schwarzschild space-time such as Isotropic, Lemaitre, or Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates and you will get different results. You can find those coordinates and many other things about the Schwarzschild space-time nicely discussed in the book *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler.